# sql server variable increment in query

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2

In MySQL I can do something like this:

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as num FROM
(select 0 union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 union all select 1) t3,
(select @row := 0) as t4;
```

The output of which is:

```
num
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I tried to do this in sql server, but met many road blocks:

First I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(select 0 union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 union all select 1) t3;
```

and received:

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't1'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't2'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't3'.
```

So I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t3;
```

1. Why do I have to specify a name for column 1 on the derived tables?

Next, I tried to setup a scalar, I guessed I had to do it this way:

```
DECLARE @row as int
SET @row = 0
```

I can do this:

```
SELECT @row = @row + 1
```

Which results in nothing back until I do `SELECT @row` which now shows a `1`

I cannot do (as I was in MySQL at the start):

```
DECLARE @row as int
SET @row = 0

SELECT @row = @row + 1 as num FROM
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t3;
```

I get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 't1'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 't3'.
```

1. How do I mimic the behavior of the first query (from MySQL) in sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you just want the row number, you could just use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in TSQL;

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.f) num FROM
  (SELECT 0 AS f UNION ALL SELECT 1) t1,
  (SELECT 0 AS f UNION ALL SELECT 1) t2,
  (SELECT 0 AS f UNION ALL SELECT 1) t3;
```

That will return the row number for each combination. `ROW_NUMBER()` requires an `ORDER BY`, so just order by the first convenient column.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7215e/4).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the intent, and if you have SQL Server 2005 or above, try this:

```
select row_number() over(order by t1.f) as num from
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t3,
(select 0 as f) as t4;
```

Yields:

```
num
--------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,  for this little query :

```
DECLARE @row as int
SET @row = 0

SELECT @row = @row + 1 as num FROM
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t3;
```

you try to give a name to variable, so setting AND outputting is what you want, that is not possible. you have to do the first or the last, not both..

```
DECLARE @row as int
SET @row = 0

SELECT @row = @row + 1 FROM
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t1,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t2,
(select 0 as f union all select 1) t3;

SELECT @row as num
```